# What instrument is Stevie Wonder playing in this video?

Tags: string-instruments

In this CBS This Morning video Stevie Wonder is talking about Aretha Franklin who has just recently passed, after a long and profound life.

What instrument is in front of him? I've never seen anything like it.

It appears to have strings, is long an flat on a table in front of him, with strings starting in front of him and extending forward directly away from him.

Video: [Stevie Wonder reveals his last words to Aretha Franklin before she died](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noRx3RxNQ1Q)

[image: Stevie Wonder and unrecognized instrument]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this instrument is a harpejji. SW had an endorsement deal with the makers.

Comment: Oh, the "strings" and "frets" are electrical contacts?

Comment: It looked like an overgrown steel guitar to me - though playing steel guitar entirely by hammering-on the strings was a novelty!

Comment: They're strings,  the playing technique is mainly 'tapping'. But check on the maker's website.  SW  endorses the instrument.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D89RpfwcEA&feature=youtu.be&list=UUV3VKY6Zh-rV6E7AXFcf_Tg